# for-loop it's not iterating completely when the array has certain size

Tags: python

when I have this array

```
 A = [1,2,3]
```

i did this basic for-loop to iterate over the entire array except the last position

```
index = 0
for i in range(1,len(A)-1):
    print(i)
    if A[i] > A[index]:
        index = i
```

it is suposed to do 2 iterations but when I print "i", this is the output

```
1
```

PS. I tried with this array and it worked absolutely fine

```
B= [7,5,14,2,8,8,10,1,2,3]
```

any hint about what is happening? thanks for your time

edit = I already put the index declaration
edit 2 = Problem solved

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: You are using range wrong.

Comment: you're starting at index 1 not 0 and going until len(A) - 1 which in the case you gave is 2, therefore from indices 1->2 only one index is printed

Comment: saving the index position of the biggest number in the array

Comment: in python, first index is 0 indeed. try this :`for i in range(0,len(A)-1):`

Comment: What's the point of `print(i)` ? you want to check if `index` is correct or not

Comment: @Carcigenicate I declare "index = 0" outside the for-loop so the range starts at 1 because there's no point of compare the same position

Comment: Why are you expecting two iterations? `range(1, len(A) - 1)` will have values from `1` until `len(A) - 1` excluded or `len(A) - 2` included. Since `len(A) == 3` you should really expect a single iteration.

Comment: @norok2 that's what confuses me because with array B it does 8 iterations

Comment: @SantiagoRamirez, because with array B, it starts from index 1 and iterates up to index len(B)-2(inclusive), i.e. 8.

Comment: @norok2 index starts at 0 for array B too you can see the code before the forloop

Comment: @SantiagoRamirez I am not sure what you mean by your comments but `len(A) == 3` so it stops at `3 - 2 = 1` included, hence 1 iteration (starting from `1`). With `B`, `len(B) == 10` so it stops at `10 - 2 = 8` included, hence 8 iterations (starting from `1`). As simple as that. Perhaps, try printing `list(range(a, b))` for various `a` and `b` to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The `range()` function returns a sequence of numbers, starting from `0` by default, and increments by `1` (by default), and ends at a specified number.

Syntax:

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

Here, one important thing to note is that the stop is exclusive. So, if you run a loop from `1` to `len(A)-1`, then actually it will run from `1` to `len(A)-2`, which is only one iteration in your code.

So, in order to do two iterations replace `range(1,len(A)-1)` with `range(0,len(A)-1)` or `range(len(A)-1)` if you want to start from index `0`, or `range(1,len(A))` if you want to start from `1` and do two iterations.

Comment: @Yeah I know this doesn't provide answer to the above question. He doesn't want answer, he just wants to know where is he doing wrong. Why he is getting just 1 iteration instead of 2.

Comment: Now, i added proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to create a list of items bigger than a certain value if so this is how:

```
a = 5
b = [1, 5, 6, 2, 10, 69, 42, 7]
c = []
for I in b:
    if I > a:
        c.append(I)
print(*c)
```

Your question is very unclear, what exactly is your objective?

Comment: actually the body of the forloop doesn't matter that much, my only problem it's why the forloop does not iterate completely with array A, I did a test with array B and it does iterated till the end